# Django Userena - Correctly override default django app templates?

Tags: python, django, web, django-templates

I've tried the directions at [link](http://blog.yourlabs.org/post/19777151073/how-to-override-a-view-from-an-external-django-app) for replacing the default app templates with templates specific to my website.

Specifically, I've set up the following file structure:

```
project_specific_app
-templates
--userena
---files_with_same_names_as_userena_templates.html
```

TEMPLATE_DIRS:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)
```

However, when I try changing the contents of "files_with_same_name_as_userena_templates.html" and restart the webserver, the webpages do not change

What else am I forgetting?

SOLUTION: After looking at TEMPLATE_DIRS in my project/settings.py and changing it to /absolute/path/to/project/specific/app/templates/ my customized templates worked.

Comment: How does your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` variable in `settings.py` look like?

Comment: TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

Comment: You should not post the answer in your question. You rather accept the answer given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is probably because you don't have any `TEMPLATE_DIRS` defined in `settings.py`. Modify it to this:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    'full/path/to/your/templates/dir',
    )
```

**TIP:** Normally, it's a good practice to avoid hard coding paths. You can do this trick instead to get the full path to the templates dir (or whatever path needed) and keep your project portable:

```
import os
settings_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(settings_dir))

...

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates/'),
)
```

Hope this helps!